# Highcharts how to use column title as X axis and not as Legend

Tags: php, highcharts

Im using highcharts to convert my table to a line graph but right now im facing a problem where I wanted to make my column title as the x axis instead of being used a the legend in the graph. Attached is the code and the screenshot of the table. I hope I can learn a solution to this problem because I am still new to highcharts.

[image]
[image]

```
   {
  "title": {
    "text": "Performance Review"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Number of Products"
    },
    "labels": {},
    "opposite": false,
    "reversed": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Quarter"
    },
    "labels": {},
    "opposite": false,
    "reversed": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "layout": "vertical",
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "middle"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "label": {
        "connectorAllowed": false
      },
      "pointStart": 1,
      "animation": false
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "Quarter 1",
      "turboThreshold": 0,
      "_colorIndex": 0,
      "_symbolIndex": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Quarter 2",
      "turboThreshold": 0,
      "_colorIndex": 1,
      "_symbolIndex": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Quarter 3",
      "turboThreshold": 0,
      "_colorIndex": 2,
      "_symbolIndex": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Quarter 4",
      "turboThreshold": 0,
      "_colorIndex": 3,
      "_symbolIndex": 3
    }
  ],
  "responsive": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "condition": {
          "maxWidth": 500
        },
        "chartOptions": {
          "legend": {
            "layout": "horizontal",
            "align": "center",
            "verticalAlign": "bottom"
          }
        },
        "_id": "highcharts-amzecb7-4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    "csv": "\"Company\";\"Quarter 1\";\"Quarter 2\";\"Quarter 3\";\"Quarter 4\"\n\"A\";24916;24916;11744;30000",
    "googleSpreadsheetKey": false,
    "googleSpreadsheetWorksheet": false
  },
  "chart": {
    "inverted": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi wt1155, I want to make sure if I understand your question. Do you want to have "Quarter 1", "Quarter 2", "Quarter 3", "Quarter 4" as categories names on xAxis?

Comment: yes i want to show the amount of products purchased of company A for each quarter of a year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set switchRowsAndColumns property to true and xAxis type to category. You can also remove series from chart options.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "title": {
    "text": "Performance Review"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": "Number of Products"
    },
    "labels": {},
    "opposite": false,
    "reversed": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    type: 'category',
    "title": {
      "text": "Quarter"
    },
    "labels": {},
    "opposite": false,
    "reversed": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "layout": "vertical",
    "align": "right",
    "verticalAlign": "middle"
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "label": {
        "connectorAllowed": false
      },
      "pointStart": 1,
      "animation": false
    }
  },
  "responsive": {
    "rules": [{
      "condition": {
        "maxWidth": 500
      },
      "chartOptions": {
        "legend": {
          "layout": "horizontal",
          "align": "center",
          "verticalAlign": "bottom"
        }
      },
      "_id": "highcharts-amzecb7-4"
    }]
  },
  "data": {
    switchRowsAndColumns: true,
    "csv": "\"Company\";\"Quarter 1\";\"Quarter 2\";\"Quarter 3\";\"Quarter 4\"\n\"A\";24916;24916;11744;30000"
  },
  "chart": {
    "inverted": false
  }
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8f3pve9w/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.switchRowsAndColumns